# How to get the share count for a Facebook post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

For over a week I'm trying to get the share count for a specific user post (that post has been directly shared by a friend).

All permissions are ok (`read_stream` included).

I've tried using the **Graph API** or via the **FQL**, all I can get is the comment count and the like count (share count doesn't even appear in the json response).

Is there something new to take into account to obtain that information?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you must be having the post id. So you can simply use the API-

`/{post-id}?fields=shares`

you'll get the response as-

```
{
  "shares": {
    "count": 999
  }, 
  "id": "POST_ID", 
  "created_time": "XXXX-XX-XX"
}
```

[Demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=386050065267_10153256675935268%3Ffields%3Dshares&version=v2.0)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Unfortunately, when I try with my POST_ID, it only returns :

`{ "id": "POST_ID", "created_time": "XXXX-XX-XX" }`

I don't receive any shares data... and I know that there is 1 share on that POST_ID.

Any idea...

Comment: Well, if that post is public can you please share the postid?

Comment: Here is the post url :
https://www.facebook.com/1383537418/posts/10203918927758588

Comment: There's no share in the link you've mentioned!

Comment: What does the "1 share" mean in that post screenshot: https://imageshack.com/i/kpbb2de9j ...

Comment: I'm not sure, but when I am clicking on the post link, I cant see such string "1 Share" ! Probably that the person who has shared has some privacy setting for this or something...

Comment: That info seems only available to people who are friends with the person who has shared that post...

Comment: Nope. That's related to the privacy setting. In the demo link that I've shared in the answer, you'll see that the share count is correct

Comment: Have you even tried the same for any other posts? It will work, please just diont stick with this post, I've already told you the reason for that

Answer (score 0):

use ajax call to obtain the result

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function setcount(id,urlForLike){
    $.ajax({
      url: urlForLike,
      success: function(data){
        // console.log(data[0].like_count);
        $("#img-"+id).append(data[0].like_count);
      }
    });
}
```

then call the function from where you want the result

```
<script>
 setcount("<?php echo 'SOMETHING UNIQUE';?>","<?php echo 'https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls='YOUR URL");
</script>
```

then place this code to display the share count

```
<span id="img-<?php echo 'SOMETHING UNIQUE'; ?>">
```

wherever there is 'SOMETHING UNIQUE' change this to id of the post or number to append the data to the div/span. ALso change 'YOUR URL' to the url of the page/link whichever suits your need.

```
[{"url":"URL","normalized_url":"URL","share_count":4,"like_count":197,"comment_count":15,"total_count":216,"click_count":0,"comments_fbid":null,"commentsbox_count":0}]
```

above json data is how the output of the ajax call